# How to find useful days including current date (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, calendar

Good morning Guys.
I'm having a problem and I think you can help me.

I need a function that returns me the last 5 business days from the current date. I can already bring all working days considering the current date, but what I really need is the last 5 days.

I need them in this order, for example:

```
Thursday: 27/12/2018
Wednesday 26/12/2018
Monday 24/12/2018
Friday 21/12/2018
Thursday 20/12/2018
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SQL> create table holidays (datum date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into holidays
  2    select date '2018-12-25' from dual union
  3    select date '2018-12-26' from dual union
  4    select date '2019-01-01' from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> with calendar as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate) - 15 + level  datum
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 15
  5    ),
  6  inter as
  7    (select datum,
  8            to_char(datum, 'day') n_day,
  9            row_number() over (order by datum desc) rn
 10     from calendar
 11     where to_char(datum, 'dy', 'nls_date_language=english') not in ('sat', 'sun')
 12       and datum not in (select datum from holidays)
 13    )
 14  select datum, n_day
 15  from inter
 16  where rn <= 5
 17  order by datum desc;

DATUM      N_DAY
---------- ---------
28/12/2018 friday
27/12/2018 thursday
24/12/2018 monday
21/12/2018 friday
20/12/2018 thursday

SQL>
```

- `HOLIDAYS` table contains dates that should be removed from the list; I put several dates that are holidays in Croatia. Yours would probably look different.
- `CALENDAR` CTE returns the last 7 days (one week) using hierarchical query
- `TO_CHAR`, along with `dy` format mask and date language set to English (if you use another language, pay attention to day names), removes Saturdays and Sundays (weekend)
- `ROW_NUMBER` is used to "sort" dates so that you'd be able to select the last 5 working days

Comment: The OP's sample output skips 25-DEC-2018 (aka Christmas Day) so presumably they do want to exclude public holidays. So the required solution is the separate table.

Comment: Presumably, yes, @APC. In Croatia, public holiday is also 26-DEC so ... separate table it is. I edited my message so that it uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Littlefoot, it helped a lot to solve my problem. But I need this list including today. Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: You're welcome. Today is now included, @João (just remove "-1" in line #2).

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, I've done it before. Sorry for not saying

Comment: No problem; I'm glad if it helped.

Comment: This is my output:
24-DEC -2018
25-DEC-2018 ... and so on.
How do I make it look like this:
24/12/2018
25/12/2018 ... and so on.

Comment: Either use TO_CHAR function with appropriate format mask, such as `to_char(datum, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` or `alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'`

Comment: Thank you bro. My issue has been resolved.